# Java Naming: Security considerations for difference between and uses of SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION and SECURITY_PROTOCOL

Tags: java, ssl, jndi

The Java documentation for `javax.naming.Context` gives short descriptions for its fields, including `SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION` and `SECURITY_PROTOCOL` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/Context.html#field_summary).

The parts of the descriptions relevant to understanding their purpose and behavior are...

for SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION:

> Constant that holds the name of the environment property for specifying the security
>       level to use. Its value is one of the following strings: "none", "simple", "strong".

for SECURITY_PROTOCOL:

> Constant that holds the name of the environment property for specifying the security
>       protocol to use. Its value is a string determined by the service provider (e.g. "ssl").

For testing, I have used "simple" authentication, which is plaintext, and "ssl" protocol.

How does this work? Will the client application connect to the server and supply the principal/credentials in plaintext then encrypt the queries and object-modifications and such, or will the entire communication go through an ssl tunnel, authentication and all, or how does that work? If everything goes through ssl when ssl protocol is specified, why does the SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION field exist? Is it to encrypt the information which is about to go through an encrypted connection (encrypted twice over)?

If everything goes through ssl if that is specified for the protocol, then I'm thinking it's safe to use "simple" and "ssl," even in production. Is there any reason not to?

This all comes down to "What are the differences between them?"

Answer (score 0):

Connection precedes authentication. The connection happens first, via SSL, then the authentication is performed. In the case of authentication via client certificate, it's all one step.

'Simple' authentication is not plaintext.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ldap/auth_mechs.html

It says simple is "clear-text"